# Multi language with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I am working on a project based on codeigniter. I can set languages by this

```
$this->lang->load('file', 'french');
$this->lang->load('file', 'german');
```

Now my question is how can I detect which language file to load? For example if I will load language after detecting ip or browser and if  user from england went to france and opening website from a cafe then  he will see website in french language..

How can I achive this? Is anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` is the language (for example en or fr)

Comment: This function is deprecated now. (PHP 4 >= 4.1.0, PHP 5)

Answer (score 0):

User will choose which language he wants to see in this website. He will choose it from the drop down or something else then you will store the same in the cookies/session and hence can show the chosen language file.

Also using ips is a little hangy in exceptional cases like corporate networks.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter save the files of default language at the start in the session array. The solution is reload this array with the new language files.

I make a small package which implement this solution easily https://github.com/oleurud/Codeigniter_Multi-language_Package